# Jquery animation effect question

Tags: jquery

I need some help on this on how can I animate the following:
If **box1** done fading in 2000ms then that is the time to start animate the **box2** the **box3** and **box4**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#box1').fadeIn(2000);
  $('#box2').fadeIn(2000);
  $('#box3').fadeIn(2000);
  $('#box4').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

How can i do this, or give me some link. I am noob in jquery
**Thank you all**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question's a but unclear, but you can use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to simplify this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#box1').fadeIn(2000);
  $('#box2').delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
  $('#box3').delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
  $('#box4').delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/9YwEM/).  If you meant one then another, then another, just change the delay, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#box1').fadeIn(2000);
  $('#box2').delay(2000).fadeIn(2000);
  $('#box3').delay(4000).fadeIn(2000);
  $('#box4').delay(6000).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/9YwEM/1/).  Or, shorten it a bit with [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) using the index parameter it passes to the callback, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#box1, #box2, #box3, #box4').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(2000*i).fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/9YwEM/2/). Or, improve it further, giving them a class so it's more extensible, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.box').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(2000*i).fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

[Test that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/9YwEM/4/) :)

Comment: Actually that last example with each is pretty cool.  Good idea.  If it used a class instead of ids it could be quite extensible to any number of elements.  Nice.

Comment: @Squeegy - absolutely! Was getting to adding that :) Takes me a bit to make the example pages

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#box1').fadeIn(2000, function() {
    $('#box2').fadeIn(2000, function() {
      $('#box3').fadeIn(2000, function() {
        $('#box4').fadeIn(2000);
      })
    })
  });
});
```

The animation functions take a second argument, which is a function that is called on completion.  You can use this to chain animations.

Though you may want to set this up in a way that it recursively calls a method where you pass in the box id, and it sets up the next in the chain until they are all faded in.  Unless all you ever have is 4 boxes, then the above code is fine.